# Give an example of a set that has $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ as its accumulation points.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Give an example of a set that has $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ as its accumulation points. My guess is that I can take, sequences that converge to each of the limits so in particular, I could take $x_{n1}=(1/n),x_{n2}=1-1/n,x_{n3}=1/2-1/n$ and in general $x_{nk}=1/(k-1)-1/n.$ The set $\{\{x_{nk}\}|k=1,2,3...\}$ would give me the desired set of accumulation points. Does this work?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But you need more arguments: for example 2/3 is not in your initial set. How do you know 2/3 is not  an accumulation point? What I mean is, you have to prove that your set has *no other limit points* than these.

Comment: @PVanchinathan any hints?

Comment: You can show there is no other accumulation point piece by piece. The complement of $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$ and hence a union of countably many open intervals. Show that no point in each of such open intervals can be an accumulation point. Remember that the open intervals are $(-\infty,0),(1,\infty),(1/2,1),(1/3,1/2),(1/4,1/3),...$

Comment: You have the right idea. One example: For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $(x_{n,j})_{j\in \Bbb N}$  be a strictly increasing sequence of members of $(1/n,1/(n+1))$ that converges to $1/n.$ Then let $S=\{0\}\cup \{x_{n,j}:n,j\in \Bbb N\}\cup \{1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider a bijective map $\varphi:\mathbb{N}^+\to \mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}^+$, $\varphi(n)=\left(\varphi_1(n),\varphi_2(n)\right)$ and define the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ through
$$ a_n = [0;\varphi_1(n),\varphi_2(n)] = \frac{1}{\varphi_1(n)+\frac{1}{\varphi_2(n)}}.$$
It is pretty clear the continued fractions of the form $[0;1,\text{whatever}]$ accumulate towards $[0;1]=1$, the continued fractions of the form $[0;2,\text{whatever}]$ accumulate towards $[0;2]=\frac{1}{2}$ and so on. Zero is also an accumulation point for the continued fractions of the form $[0;m,m]$.

The structure of the ordinary continued fractions allows to state that $0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots$ are the only accumulation points of our sequence. Your construction does not immediately allow to state the same.

---

This should be well-known, if it is not, in your case, you may prove it as an interesting sub-exercise.
We may take $\varphi$ as
$$ \varphi(n)=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}+1}{2}\right\rfloor,n-\frac{1}{2}\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}+1}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}+1}{2}\right\rfloor-1\right)\right). $$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $$\{\frac{1}{n}|n \in \Bbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}=A$$

Take the set $$A+A=\{x_1+x_2|x_1,x_2 \in A\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting natural example:

Let $A_m=\left\{  \frac{1}{m} -\frac{1}{n}\cdot(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}) \right\}_{n\ge2}$

Observe that $\frac{1}{n}\cdot[\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}]$ is always less than $\frac{1}{2} \cdot[\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}]$ which is the half the distance between $\frac{1}{m}$ and $\frac{1}{m+1}$.

Now $A= \cup_{m=1}^{\infty} A_m$ is the desired set.